# Edit Image FaceBook Style

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i got a script after searching google for Edit Image FaceBook Style but found no html element in the script. so my concern is how to use it. the url is [enter link description here](http://netindonesia.net/blogs/cipto/archive/2009/10/24/jquery-plugin-edit-image-facebook-style.aspx)

can anyone tell me how to use in my aspx file with small samle code.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is plugin, you should use it like any other plugin in jquery:

```
$('#your_element').editFaceBook();
```

Comment: can u please tell me which element i should use...,<img> element? suppose my img tag look like <img src="images/mypic.gif" id="img1"> $('#img1').editFaceBook(); then it will work?

Answer (score 3):

Its work's only in `<div>` tag like this :

```
<div id="#img1">
</div>
```

it will not work if you use or call app like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   $("#img1").editFaceBook();

</script>
```

it will only work if you use inside docoument read function

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function(){

   $("#img1").editFaceBook();

   });
</script>
```